# Why would someone prefer halfwave rectifier over bridge rectifier?

Tags: design, power-electronics, rectifier, full-bridge

The other day, out of curiosity I was measuring the current wave shape of a laptop charger. The wave shape indicated a spike only in one half cycle. I'm guessing half wave rectifier here.

One thing that kept me thinking was Why would someone prefer a half wave over full bridge and full wave rectifier? 
I'm guessing lower BOM cost / the 1.4V drop across the diodes.

Or was it just the designers choice and there's no point in thinking about it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate +1, your answer there has everything in it.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few good reasons: -

- Only one diode forward voltage drop
- Only one diode as opposed to four
- 0V can be an incoming power line as well as the outgoing DC side
- You can use one secondary of a transformer and two diodes to get a split V, 0, -V supply: -

[image]